# Can I omit the verb 'drew/was/became'?

Tags: correlative-constructions

In the following sentence, can I omit the verb 'drew/was/became)? If so, how is the grammar rule?

> The nearer her wedding day (drew), the more nervous she (was/became).

Comment: You can't completely omit them. You can replace them with synonyms, though

Answer (score 1):

You can omit "drew", since it's implied:

> The nearer her wedding day, the more nervous she was/became.

It's called an [Textual Ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/ellipsis) - When we can easily understand everything in the sentence because of the surrounding text.

You can't remove was/became since the sentence could no longer be understood. The more nervous she... what? Made other people?